# Consulta SQL en BBDD de WP_usermeta

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysqli

Quiero hacer una consulta en la BBDD de Wordpress ya que estoy creando una pagina que hace lo siguiente, según el usuario que esta registrado, este tiene unos referidos, los referidos al registrarse hay un custom field que es patrocinador el cual se añade en la BBDD correctamente en la tabla `wp_usermeta`.

La pregunta es cual sería la consulta sql para coger el nickname de mi referido y el tipo de usuario que es.

Esta consulta estaría bien

```
  SELECT * 
   FROM wp_usermeta um1 
   WHERE um1.user_id IN ( SELECT um2.user_id FROM wp_usermeta um2 WHERE    um2.meta_key = 'id_patrocinador' and um2.meta_value = '"$patrocinador"')AND    um1.meta_key = 'nickname'
```

Pongo una imagen de la tabla `wp_usermeta` para que veáis como es la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar la consulta en la BBDD para saber si estaría bien o no, me salen los resultados que yo quiero, ahora el siguiente paso es guardar el nickname de los usuarios que salgan en variables para imprimirlos por pantalla.

Comment: La consulta tiene buena pinta. Aunque sin conocer la estructura de la base de datos no podemos decirte si es correcta.

Comment: esto lo he probado en la bbdd y me da errores, edito la pregunta y pongo foto de la bbdd

Comment: Cómo estás preguntando por el usuario? Con `$current_user`? En la Query de arriba tienes `Usuario registrado`, pero entiendo que no estarás inténtandolo así.

Comment: No,para preguntar y obtener los valores del usuario lo pregunto asi if (is_user_logged_in()){
$cu = wp_get_current_user();
$patrocinador=$cu->user_login ;
} y en la query no pongo usuario registrado pongo la varaible que es $patrocinador

Comment: Cuál es el error que te marca? Intenta poner toda la información posible cuando realizas una pregunta, todo esto es relevante.

Comment: Esta es la consulta que hagoSELECT nickname,wp_capabilities FROM wp_usermeta WHERE patrocinador= aitor
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

Error que me da: #1054 - Unknown column 'nickname' in 'field list'

Comment: Si te fijas la Tabla tiene unas columna llamadas userd_id,meta_key y meta_value

Comment: `nickname` es un registro, no es un nombre de columna. Tienes un buen lio en esa tabla. Los nombres de la columna no los vemos en esa foto.

Comment: Toda la razón, los nombres de las columnas te las digo yo:  
umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value, claro yo lo que quiero es hacer una consulta para los registros que he indicado en la consulta.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = "aitor"`. Esto en el supuesto que tengas `aitor` bajo la columna `user_id`, que como ya he dicho no puedo verlo, eso compruebalo tu.

Comment: el user_id es un numero, tendre que obtener l id de ese user que esta registrado verdad? y esta consulta que es lo que hace?

Comment: Esa consulta saca TODOS los campos de la tabla que cumplan la condición. Realmente no sé que es lo que quieres sacar viendo la estructura que tienes, por lo que no puedo ayudar mucho más.

Comment: A ver en la pregunta he comentado que quier hacer lo siguiente: Cuando el usuario registrado este en la pagina de mis referidos el vea todos los usuarios que ha registrado el con su id de patrocinador que para eso es la variable patrocinador, lo que quiero hacer es que todos los usuarios que tengan el patrocinador con el nombre que este logeado aparezca una lista un arbol por así decirlo de los usuarios que ha registrado

Comment: El problema es que tienes las tablas mal estructuradas, piensa la estructura de las tablas y después lo podrás sacar de manera fácil. Ahora mismo tienes una única tabla, en la que es imposible que tenga las relaciones que comentas. Haz un dibujo de las tablas con sus columnas y piensa como las vas a relacionar, muéstralas en tu pregunta si lo ves oportuno y que podamos ayudarte. Das por hecho que conocemos la estructura que tienes o crees tener, pero no nos la has enseñado, por lo que no podemos hacer la consulta que buscas.

Comment: si puedes, pasate por el [chat], estas confundiendo la estructura de la tabla con los registros de la tabla (lo que agregaste fue un registro, no un campo). Igual no deberias tocar las tablas wp, ya que son las internas de word_press, deberias generar tus propias tablas para eso, en la misma base.

Comment: Gracias a @muriano he avanzado en el tema, ahora ya tengo la consulta que quiero, ahora solo he de sacar las filas y guardarlas en variables

Answer (score 0):

Os pongo la solución final y con muestra de niveles.

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM wp_usermeta um1 
WHERE um1.user_id IN ( SELECT um2.user_id FROM wp_usermeta um2 WHERE um2.meta_key = 'id_del_referido' and um2.meta_value = '".$patrocinador."')AND um1.meta_key = 'nickname'";

$results1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('ok');


while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($results1)) {
$query2 = "SELECT * 
FROM wp_usermeta um1 
WHERE um1.user_id IN ( SELECT um2.user_id FROM wp_usermeta um2 WHERE um2.meta_key = 'id_del_referido' and um2.meta_value = '".$fila[3]."')AND um1.meta_key = 'nickname'";
$results2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die('ok');
echo '<ul class="lista-nivel-uno">
<li>'.$fila[3].'</li>';
while ($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_row($results2)) {
echo '<ul class="lista-nivel-dos><li>'.$fila2[3].'</li></ul>
</ul>';
}
}
```